# Javascript set up Timeout Functions within a for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, timing

I have a loop that select and object and fades that object in, but when the loop is executed the object id stays at the last entry;

```
    var ordered = Array(elements.length);
            var x = 0;
            $('#' + that.options.slide_name + '_' + that.nextslide).children().each(function () {
                ordered[x] = $(this);
                $(this).fadeOut(1);
                $(this).attr('id','current_slide_content_' + x);
                x++;
            });
//fade each element
            var time = that.options.fade_speed / ordered.length
            var overlap = time / that.options.fade_step;
            //time = time + overlap;
            var wait = 0;
            var num = 0;
            var i = null;
            var funcs = Array(ordered.length);
            for(var a = 0; a < ordered.length; a++){
                var w = wait;
                var id = $('#current_slide_content_' + a);
                window.setTimeout( function (event) {
                    id.fadeIn(time);
                    console.log(id);
                },w);
                //$('#current_slide_content_' + a).fadeIn(time);  <-- on its own works, error is with the wait time
                wait = time + wait; 
            }
```

I narrowed down the error to be in the final loop that actually adds the timeout function.

```
for(var a = 0; a < ordered.length; a++){
                var w = wait;
                var id = $('#current_slide_content_' + a);
                window.setTimeout( function (event) {
                    id.fadeIn(time);
                    console.log(id);
                },w);
                //$('#current_slide_content_' + a).fadeIn(time);  <-- on its own works, error is with the wait time
                wait = time + wait; 
            }
```

When the id of the element is logged it should be:

foo_0
foo_1
foo_2

But instead it displays as:

foo_2
foo_2
foo_2

I have been on this for days and restarted several times, how do i format the id correctly for each of my Timeout functions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

should try :

```
window.setTimeout( (function(time_, id_){
    return function (event) {
        id_.fadeIn(time_);
        console.log(id_);
    }
})(time,id),w);
```

This is a closure to save the value of `time` and `id` in the scope of the function

Comment: I would say fix the inner `id.fadeIn` to `id_.fadeIn` and it looks like it's ready to go ;)

Comment: I cant believe it was something a simple as that, thanks